# Javascript (html) Math.random() range not working

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to generate a random number between "lowestnum" and "highestnum". they are inputs by the user.

i used this code in my  but the number generated is not within the range

```
var secret = Math.floor(Math.random()*(highestnum-lowestnum+1)+lowestnum);
```

for example: i typed in lowest=4, highest=6, secret **should be** either 4/5/6. but in fact, number generated is 0/1/2. i found out that it is because 6-4 is 2, and it will only generate 0 to 2, which is the difference between the number, but not any number between 4 to 6

**edited! updated clearer question**

these are what its inside html

````
<input id="highestnum" type="text" name="highestnum"> ```

and inside javascript is this 
```var lowestnum = document.getElementById("lowestnum").value; 
var highestnum = document.getElementById("highestnum").value; 
var secret = Math.floor(Math.random()*(highestnum-lowestnum+1)+lowestnum);```
````

Comment: Where are the `lowestnum` and `highestnum` inputs in that HTML? You’ve overwriting the arguments of 11 and 63 with their values. Also, if `min` is a string, `+ min` will concatenate with it instead of adding.

Comment: these are what its inside html
```<input id="lowestnum" type="text" name="lowestnum">
<input id="highestnum" type="text" name="highestnum">```

and inside javascript is this 
```var lowestnum = document.getElementById("lowestnum").value;
var highestnum = document.getElementById("highestnum").value;
var secret = Math.floor(Math.random()*(highestnum-lowestnum+1)+lowestnum);```

Comment: min and max are strings

Comment: @javadead you can not take integer value directly in Javascript because they consider as a string so you need to convert it to an integer using the `JS parseInt()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
function randomNumber() 
{

    var lowestnum =  parseInt(document.getElementById("lowestnum").value);
    var highestnum = parseInt(document.getElementById("highestnum").value);
    secret=Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.abs(highestnum - lowestnum) + 1) + lowestnum); 
    console.log(secret);
}

window.onload = function() {

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    var lowestnum =  document.getElementById("lowestnum");
    var highestnum = document.getElementById("highestnum");
if (event.target === lowestnum || event.target === highestnum ) {
    if(lowestnum.value.length > 0 && highestnum .value.length>0){
        document.getElementById("button").removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("button").setAttribute("disabled","true");
    }
}

}, false);

}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="lowestnum">
<input type="number" id="highestnum">
<button type="button" disabled id="button">generate</button>
```

**UPDATE** just parse it to int

Comment: did you test this? Use 10 and 12

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, but the range seems to not work. the answer i receive is still not right. random number generated is not within the range i input, in fact, the number generated is within the difference of the number i input.

Comment: give some example @javadead

Comment: for example: i typed in lowest=4, highest=6, secret **should be** either 4/5/6. but in fact, number generated is 0/1/2. i found out that it is because 6-4 is 2, and it will only generate 0 to 2, which is the difference between the number, but not any number between 4 to 6.

Comment: hi, i just saw the updated version with "parseint", and it works!! thank you!

Comment: I think this is your answer. Test it! @javadead

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

**Getting a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive):**

```
function getRandom() {
  return Math.random();
}
```

**Getting a random number between two values:**

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

**Getting a random integer between two values:**

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
```

**Getting a random integer between two values, inclusive:**

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); //The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive 
}
```